# concatenating a string per letter

Tags: javascript, string

I have users inputting letters a single char into a time through an input field. Each char is taken and saved into an array called `rightLtrsArr`.

What I need to do is take all the letters that are stored in that array as separate elements and make them into a string. The string would be updated for each letter the user enters. Since I know I can't push a new char into a string, but would have to concatenate two strings together to create a new one, I've been trying to do this through a loop like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rightLtrsArr.length; i ++){
    guessedWord = rightLtrsArr.concat([i]);
    console.log("the guessed word is " + guessedWord);
}
```

Needless to say, this hasn't worked out so well. Is my syntax wrong? What am I missing here?

Comment: To combine an array of letters into a string, you can do `rightLtrsArr.join('')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the useful JavaScript function called [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) that is made for just this purpose - joining an array. You can use it like this:

```js
let rightLtrsArr = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];

let guessedWord = rightLtrsArr.join('');
console.log("the guessed word is " + guessedWord);
```

Note: The parameter is what to separate the elements by - in this case we don't want to separate them so we pass an empty string.

Note 2: You can use this function to join not only single characters but any array.

Comment: Also, for future reference if you want to use concat(), this should be the way to make it work: guessedWord = guessedWord.concat(rightLtrsArr[i]);

Comment: Can I ask you one more? Now that I have two strings, I need to compare them, but the letters are in different orders. Is there a way to re-sort the letters to match another string? Or can I compare two strings to see if they're equal regardless of order but just by value and length? For instance, if guessedWord ends up being ssagl and the word I'm comparing it to is glass, it could still be equal because they're the same letters of the same length but different order?

Comment: It would be easier to sort them with `Array.prototype.sort` while they are arrays and join them afterwards, so you can compare them easily. Otherwise you can use `split` to make them arrays and do the same.

Comment: I was actually thinking the same thing and tried it. My guessedWordArr sorts fine but the randomWordArr won't re-sort :(

Comment: You can ask another question add a bit more context so we can help you

Comment: Yeah. It's like the original post says. Users input a single char at a time stored in an array. A random word is generated and stored in another array. I don't know what order the users will enter the chars so my thought was to sort the arrays and then compare them to see if they're equal. But the sort method is failing for the random comp generated word so I tried to go for this string method...

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable, and then append to that in your loop.

```
     let guessedWord = "";
     for(let i = 0; i < rightLtrsArr.length; i++){
            guessedWord += rightLtrsArr[i];
     }
     console.log("the guessed word is " + guessedWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
rightLtrsArr = ['a','b','c']
guessedWord = '';

for (var i = 0; i < rightLtrsArr.length; i ++){
    guessedWord = guessedWord.concat(rightLtrsArr[i]);
}

console.log("the guessed word is " + guessedWord);

// Alternative:
// console.log("the guessed word is " + rightLtrsArr.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate the characters in your array you might need to do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rightLtrsArr.length; i ++){
    guessedWord += rightLtrsArr[i];
}
console.log("the guessed word is " + guessedWord);
```

I am not familiar with the `.concat()` function but please let me know if this works.

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/82ywpwrz/) fiddle out.

Answer (score 0):

There's a shortcut to do what you want:

`rightLtrsArr.join('')`

.join() combines joins all of the elements of an array into a string. As for a solution more like yours, you should start with an empty string and append it.

```
var guessedWord = "";
for (var i = 0; i < rightLtrsArr.length; i ++){
    guessedWord += rightLtrsArr[i];
};
console.log("the guessed word is " + guessedWord);
```